# Magento 2.4.5 deploy setup:upgrade error rejected_execution_exception","reason":"rejected execution of coordinating

Tags: magento2

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"rejected_execution_exception","reason":"rejected execution of coordinating operation [coordinating_and_primary_bytes=87418457, replica_bytes=0, all_bytes=87418457, coordinating_operation_bytes=18166365, max_coordinating_and_primary_bytes=103795916]"}],"type":"rejected_execution_exception","reason":"rejected execution of coordinating operation [coordinating_and_primary_bytes=87418457, replica_bytes=0, all_bytes=87418457, coordinating_operation_bytes=18166365, max_coordinating_and_primary_bytes=103795916]"},"status":429}
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"rejected_execution_exception","reason":"rejected execution of coordinating operation [coordinating_and_primary_bytes=87418457, replica_bytes=0, all_bytes=87418457, coordinating_operation_bytes=18166365, max_coordinating_and_primary_bytes=103795916]"}],"type":"rejected_execution_exception","reason":"rejected execution of coordinating operation [coordinating_and_primary_bytes=87418457, replica_bytes=0, all_bytes=87418457, coordinating_operation_bytes=18166365, max_coordinating_and_primary_bytes=103795916]"},"status":429} in /app/Module/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:693
Stack trace:
#0 /app/Module/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php(333): Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->process4xxError(Array, Array, Array)
#1 /app/Module/vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php(28): Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->Elasticsearch\Connections\{closure}(Array)
#2 /app/Module/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php(134): React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->then(Object(Closure), NULL)
#3 /app/Module/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php(168): React\Promise\Promise::React\Promise\{closure}(Object(React\Promise\FulfilledPromise))
#4 /app/Module/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php(231): React\Promise\Promise->settle(Object(React\Promise\FulfilledPromise))
#5 /app/Module/vendor/react/promise/src/Deferred.php(36): React\Promise\Promise::React\Promise\{closure}(Array)
#6 /app/Module/vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Client/CurlMultiHandler.php(248): React\Promise\Deferred->resolve(Array)
#7 /app/Module/vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Client/CurlMultiHandler.php(139): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Client\CurlMultiHandler->processMessages()
#8 /app/Module/vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Future/BaseFutureTrait.php(118): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Client\CurlMultiHandler->execute()
#9 /app/Module/vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Future/BaseFutureTrait.php(55): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\FutureArray->invokeWait()
#10 /app/Module/vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Future/BaseFutureTrait.php(118): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\FutureArray->wait()
#11 /app/Module/vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Future/BaseFutureTrait.php(55): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\FutureArray->invokeWait()
#12 /app/Module/vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Future/MagicFutureTrait.php(30): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\FutureArray->wait()
#13 /app/Module/vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Future/FutureArray.php(20): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\FutureArray->__get('_value')
#14 /app/Module/vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-core/Index/AsyncIndexOperation.php(113): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\FutureArray->offsetGet('items')
#15 /app/Module/vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-core/Index/AsyncIndexOperation.php(130): Smile\ElasticsuiteCore\Index\AsyncIndexOperation->resolveFutureBulks()
#16 /app/Module/vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-core/Indexer/GenericIndexerHandler.php(128): Smile\ElasticsuiteCore\Index\AsyncIndexOperation->refreshIndex(Object(Smile\ElasticsuiteCore\Index\Index))
#17 /app/Module/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(176): Smile\ElasticsuiteCore\Indexer\GenericIndexerHandler->saveIndex(Array, Object(Generator))
#18 /app/Module/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(236): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext->executeByDimensions(Array)
#19 [internal function]: Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext->Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\{closure}()
#20 /app/Module/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/ProcessManager.php(88): call_user_func(Object(Closure))
#21 /app/Module/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/ProcessManager.php(75): Magento\Indexer\Model\ProcessManager->simpleThreadExecute(Array)
#22 /app/Module/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext.php(239): Magento\Indexer\Model\ProcessManager->execute(Array)
#23 /app/Module/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext->executeFull()
#24 /app/Module/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Interceptor->___callParent('executeFull', Array)
#25 /app/Module/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#26 /app/Module/generated/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Interceptor->___callPlugins('executeFull', Array, Array)
#27 /app/Module/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer.php(443): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Interceptor->executeFull()
#28 /app/Module/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Indexer/DependencyDecorator.php(268): Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer->reindexAll()
#29 /app/Module/vendor/magento/module-indexer/Console/Command/IndexerReindexCommand.php(110): Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\DependencyDecorator->reindexAll()
#30 /app/Module/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Indexer\Console\Command\IndexerReindexCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#31 /app/Module/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#32 /app/Module/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Indexer\Console\Command\IndexerReindexCommand\Interceptor->___callParent('run', Array)
#33 /app/Module/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Indexer\Console\Command\IndexerReindexCommand\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#34 /app/Module/generated/code/Magento/Indexer/Console/Command/IndexerReindexCommand/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Indexer\Console\Command\IndexerReindexCommand\Interceptor->___callPlugins('run', Array, Array)
#35 /app/Module/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Magento\Indexer\Console\Command\IndexerReindexCommand\Interceptor->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#36 /app/Module/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Magento\Indexer\Console\Command\IndexerReindexCommand\Interceptor), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#37 /app/Module/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(116): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#38 /app/Module/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#39 /app/Module/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#40 {main}
  thrown in /app/Module/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php on line 693
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The maximum heap size for OpenSearch has been increased to 2GiB.**

**Magento Enterprise:**

The solution is to submit a support ticket to Adobe cloud. Support response.

**Magento community:**

OpenSearchServer Allowing more RAM
The memory allocated to OSS is defined by the JAVA_OPTS options.

For Linux/Mac (start.sh)

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1G -Xmx1G"
```

For Windows (start.bat)

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1G -Xmx1G
```